# How do I add authentication SOAP Header to the RPC webservice Client?

Tags: web-services, header, rpc, soap-client

I want to consume RPC webservice.I have created stub. Service requests below headers in SOAP request.

```
<S:Header>
    <securityHeader>
        <username>FUNC_DBSOCKET_SERVICE</username>
        <password>welcome1</password>
    </securityHeader>
</S:Header>
```

How can we add header to the RPC client SOAP requests.Please help.